# Convert string array to another type

Tags: c#

I'm trying to convert the string separated by commas which has 7 values of:

```
2014-21-2,1207.81,1209.87,1202.84,1203.79,1862300,1203.79
```

To another model which is:

```
return lines[1].Split(',').Select(i => new StockModel
{
    StockDate = DateTime.ParseExact(i.ToString(), "yyyy-MM-dd", null),
    StockOpen = float.Parse(i.ToString()),
    StockHigh = float.Parse(i.ToString()),
    StockLow = float.Parse(i.ToString()),
    StockClose = float.Parse(i.ToString()),
    StockVolume = Convert.ToInt32(i.ToString()),
    StockAdjustedClose = float.Parse(i.ToString()),
    StockSymbol = stockSymbol

}).SingleOrDefault();
```

However I get errors such as: `Additional information: Input string was not in a correct format.` http://s17.postimg.org/ro4k3tzct/Screenshot_1.png

If I do it manually like: `DateTime date = DateTime.Parse(lines[1].Split(',')[0])`, it works fine.

Whatever value I'm trying to put into the new Model, I get errors such as this one.

Comment: `2/21/2014` doesn't match `yyyy-MM-dd`. Isn't it obvious for you?

Comment: You're missing a coma on one line, and you have an extra one on another line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, I see the problem. You shouldn't use `Select` here. Try following instead:

```
var i = lines[1].Split(',');

return new StockModel()
{
    StockDate = DateTime.ParseExact(i[0].ToString(), "yyyy-MM-dd", null),
    StockOpen = float.Parse(i[1].ToString()),
    StockHigh = float.Parse(i[2].ToString()),
    StockLow = float.Parse(i[3].ToString()),
    StockClose = float.Parse(i[4].ToString()),
    StockVolume = Convert.ToInt32(i[5].ToString()),
    StockAdjustedClose = float.Parse(i[6].ToString()),
    StockSymbol = stockSymbol
};
```

Comment: Yeah, this would probably work and I was going to end up doing this. The select makes so much sense to me but it seems it dosent work.

Comment: `Select` would work if you'd try to get one `StockModel` instance for each part of the string. What you really need is one `StockModel` for the entire line.

Comment: Oh, I get it now. My brain just went flop during the process.